# Splitting tag libreoffice into libreoffice-writer and others?

Tags: discussion

1,284 questions have been tagged with `libreoffice` which covers a range of different software.

Is it potentially beneficial to introduce the following tags to better filter answers for the respective tool of the suite?

- `libreoffice-writer`
- `libreoffice-calc`
- `libreoffice-impress`

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is beneficial if these tags to be created ?

Comment: @Serg please see my edit.

Comment: If you want to propose tag changes, then you need to propose the reasons as well.

Comment: Do you think that separate tags make filtering for the different products easier?

Comment: @Serg A possible benefit of creating separate tags would be for questions about fixing a bug that affects only one of the applications in the LibreOffice suite. I have seen questions about bugs that affect only one LO app on the Ask LibreOffice website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ask Ubuntu introduces new tags for different applications in the LibreOffice suite, there will still need to be a [libreoffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice) tag for questions about installing and updating LibreOffice.

Creating new tags for each application in the LibreOffice suite would create six new tags, making a total of seven LibreOffice tags. These seven LibreOffice tags are already used at Superuser Q&A. To me that makes sense because there are different user experiences with each one of the LibreOffice applications. If there were seven LibreOffice tags, there wouldn't be much overlap between the different tags, so searching for questions about using a particular LibreOffice application would be easier. For example, if there is a bug in the Base database application, having a separate tag for LibreOffice 
Base would make questions about fixing that bug easier to find.

I don't recommend creating a set of overlapping tags because this will create a source of confusion that will lead to problems reviewing questions about LibreOffice.